# In a line chart, changing line order on hover

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a line chart with multiple overlapping lines. Sometimes, some of the lines can be buried under the others (with some points sticking out here and there). Not much we can do about that.

But to help visualize the data, I'd like to have a line drawn over the other one if my cursor is over one of its points (and/or any part of the line).

I searched the documentation and googled what I can, but I'm lost here. I thought there would be some setting for that, something like a "hoverOrder" property, but I'm not finding anything.

I'm under the impression that it would be possible to do it using a tooltip event to change or reorder my dataset, but it seems overly complicated (but maybe it isn't?)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks !

Comment: It depends what' you mean by "order". Really, for something to appear "above" something else its a matter of styling it such that it has that appearance. Unless youve got some custom styling anyway, the order they appear in the DOM wont matter. Chart.js appears to have no first-class concept of "order" but maybe order does imply something being "on top" of something else in its default styles. Is that the case? If you manually change the order does it render differently visually or the same? If not, the most obvious way I can think of is to fade out non hovered lines using `opacity`.

Comment: I was under the impression that the dataset had an "order" property that was used for the rendering order (the higher number appearing "deeper" - see links below). But the opacity idea is great too if the order thing doesn't work as I expect. My main issue is knowing which line is currently "under the cursor" so I can change its dataset... [doc dataset](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) / [doc order](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html#drawing-order)

Comment: Ah sorry i see was wrong about the order! Ifully understand your predicament now. Are you using `react-chartjs` ? https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2. This'll be move easier to solve if so. You need to get the mosueover event of the line, and then use this to change the `order` property in the config.

Comment: it's not possible to recognize when the cursor is over the line but only is over the points. You can try if you are not using nay tension. See discussion https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/discussions/11066